# Hero banner carousel with Gatsby + Contentful + react responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, contentful

Trying to use one of the most popular "Slider carousel" packages available react-responsive-carousel but can't fond out how to use it with a static site setup with Gatsby + Contentful. I am trying to run this code locally.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/';
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  heroImage: {
    height: '80vh',
  },
}));

const HeroCarousel = ({ data }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Carousel>
      <div>
        <BackgroundImage
          fluid={data.heroImage.fluid}
          className={classes.heroImage}
        />
        {/* <Img fluid={data.heroImage.fluid} className={classes.heroImage} /> */}
      </div>
      <div>
        <BackgroundImage
          fluid={data.heroImage.fluid}
          className={classes.heroImage}
        />
        {/* <Img fluid={data.heroImage.fluid} className={classes.heroImage} /> */}
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default HeroCarousel;
```

Parent where the query endpoint to Contentful here worked find before:

```
...
const RootIndex = ({ data }) => {
  const [author] = data.allContentfulPerson.edges;
  const news = data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges;
  return (
    <>
      <HeroCarousel showThumbs={false} data={author.node} /> *Here is the component*
      {/* <HeroBanner data={author.node} /> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default RootIndex;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  ...
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. Might as well leave this question here as this might be a nice setup for image sliders on server side rendered sites and the gatsby-image has some powerful image optimization built in.

This little fix works:

```
<Carousel showThumbs={false}>
```